# Why does PHP treat classes and functions differently regarding namespaces and autoload?

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

You can't alias a namespaced function to just the function name and you can't autoload functions. It would be nice if you could autoload functions and alias functions as just the function name.

So why is it like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jury is still out on that one.

See [Feature Request #63263](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62162)

It's been open since 2012 so don't hold your breath.

It does make mention of a potential work around of defining or including functions on an abstract class declaration and them making it in so referencing

```
/My/Custom/Namespace/Abstract::LOAD_FUNCTIONS;
```

and allowing the class autoloader to include the abstract class which either also declare the functions or includes the declaration of the function as a means to include a group of functions. To me this fills hackey but it might work for your use case.